# Simulating Map Reduce environment

Tags: mapreduce, processing

For designing some algorithm I need to simulate the map-reduce environment. I assume that I have couple of jobs and each of them consists of set of map and reduce tasks. I have to make assumption about processing time of maps and reduce tasks.
For example job "j1" has 3 map tasks and 2 reduce tasks. Now is there any constraint in processing time of map tasks vs reduce tasks? How is it usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult to make any assumptions without knowing what your map and reduce tasks do. The processing time of the map or reduce tasks of depends entirely on what you want them to do, you can't really make a blanket assumption.

For example, your individual map function could be processing an individual file as input, or an individual line, or an individual word, all of which directly effect the processing time.

The reducer is the same way; it could do a lot of processing, a little processing, or even no processing at all. (With Hadoop's implementation of MapReduce, you don't even have to have a reducer for your MapReduce task, evidencing the fact that the amount of processing varies). It just depends what the individual task calls for.

If you have an idea of what the simulated MapReduce jobs would actually be doing, you can use that to determine what the general processing times of the different tasks would be in comparison to each other.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. My concern is that if I make assumption that processing time of each map is more than each reduce, does it make sense? I mean I can find a case in reality which is p(map)>p(reduce)

Comment: @sweet There are situations in which that would make sense, yes. I was trying to get the point across that it depends entirely on what you want the map and reduce functions to do. So if you want to assume that p(map) > p(reduce), then sure, there are situations where that would happen. Since it seems you're using them in an abstract sense not based on actual functions, if that's what you need to assume, then you can definitely assume that.